# Polymorphism - why not overloading instead

Tags: c#, polymorphism, overloading, overriding

So I am learning the Polymorphism now, i simply cannot understand why would i override a function in the base class from the subclass instead of overloading the function in the base class so i could call it with different parameters.
Could someone please explain this to me?
Maybe I am just missing something here..

Comment: Please show an example of what you say :)

Comment: So you can have different subclasses behave differently in response to the same call.

Comment: The two things you're describing are very different things.  It's not clear what you're asking.  Function overloading has nothing to do with polymorphism.

Comment: Please, please, please, learn about interfaces and composition, rather than polymorphism. Inheritance is increasingly falling out of favour, so learn what's regarded as good practice instead.